# NServiceBus support .NetCore or not?

Tags: nservicebus, .net-core-rc2

I read some article about `NServiceBus` and i want use it, but i dont know it fully supported the `.NetCore` or not, i googled about it (and found some information like [This](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/4179)), but it could not help me much, any one can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Starting from [NServiceBus 7.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NServiceBus/7.0.1) they introduce support on .NET Standard 2.0 and thus can run on .NET Core 2.1+.

[Building endpoints with .NET Core 3.1](https://docs.particular.net/samples/netcore-reference/) explains how to configure it on .NET Core 3.1 and generic host.

**Original answer:**

[NServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NServiceBus/) package has no dependency on any NetStandard so it means it cannot run on Core CLR. You can use it in .NET Core projects only if you target Full .NET Framework, not .NET Core.

Comment: Question for you - it looks like they have added support for .net Core in the past 3 years and, lucky you, your answer is the top one on google when I search for nservicebus .net core.  Would you be able to update your answer saying that support was added at some point, or I can for you?

Comment: @dsolimano thanks for the comment! I have updated my answer feel free to extend it as you find best if you like.

Answer (score 1):

As of 24 April 2017 NServiceBus does not support .net core. The most current public status is this https://particular.net/blog/nservicebus-on-net-core-why-not

However I can say that internally to Particular significant effort is being put into getting .net standard support shipped.

I will add this question to the list of follow ups for after we ship

Answer (score 1):

Update: Particular Software announced upcoming support for .NET Core 2.0 on their company blog here: https://particular.net/blog/nservicebus-on-net-core-its-time